# Java 8 CompletableFuture returning a subtype from the declaration

Tags: java, completable-future

Sorry for the poor title, if someone has a better idea I'm open to suggestion.

I was playing around with the `CompletableFuture` and I stumbled upon something strange.

Let's say you have 2 classes: `A` and `B` where `B extends A`, so `B` is a subtype of `A`.

Now, let's declare a `CompletableFuture`:

```
CompletableFuture<A> promiseofA = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new B());
```

This is working because `B` being a subtype of `A` it conforms to the declaration of the `CompletableFuture`. Now, if I want to  add a `exceptionally` step, then I have a compiling exception:

```
CompletableFuture<A> promiseOfA = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new B())
                                                   .exceptionally(ex -> new B());
```

In this case Java is complaining, stating that:

```
Compilation error[ java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<B> cannot be converted to java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<A>]
```

Why is it working without the `excepionally` step and not with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not work when you add `exceptionally` because it is completely dependant on the source future for its typing.

This means that for exceptionally it sees that the source future is `CompletableFuture<B>`, then the type it returns MUST be `CompletableFuture<B>`.

If you specify that the source is actually `CompletableFuture<A>` (`CompletableFuture.<A>supplyAsync(...)`) then it will correctly compile again. It is a problem with the generic type deduction in Java.

Comment: specifically: it is the inference of the Supplier function type, you could also do `...supplyAsync((Supplier<A>)() -> new B()...` or just `...supplyAsync(() -> (A)new B()...`

Answer (score 0):

I added wildcard which extends A with exceptionally, and the compilation error was gone:

```
CompletableFuture<? extends A> promiseOfA1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new B())
            .exceptionally(ex -> new B());
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise to use `extends`/`super` in a `CompletableFuture` declarations as it would prevent some further calls on it. For example, you won't be able to call `exceptionnally()` on `promiseOfA1`.

Comment: Hum, from my understanding this is what he does there, calling `.exceptionally()` on it, no?

Comment: @MartinGOYOT Here he is calling it on the result of `suppliyAsync()`, not on `promiseOfA1` – which would be prevented by its static type.